# How to design page layout in plain TeX using OPmac?

Tags: boxes, plain-tex, opmac

I'm trying to create a slideshow in TeX using Opmac.

I need a page layout like that:
[image]

And I try this code:

```
\input opmac
\chyph

\margins/1 a5l (1,1,1,1.2)cm        % page format
\input ctimes  \typosize[17/22]      % font

\def\pg{\vfil\break}                % new page
\begitems                           % start items

% set font
\letfont\titfont=\tenbf at18pt 
\letfont\subfont=\tenbf at16pt 

% set header
\headline={\ifnum\folio=1\hfill\else{\hbox to\hsize{\hfil \subfont \firstmark \hfil}}\fi}

% set footer
\newtoks\leftfoot \leftfoot={\hfill Footer text}
\newtoks\rightfoot \rightfoot={\hfill \subfont\folio} 
\footline={\ifnum\folio=1\hfill\else\the\leftfoot\the\rightfoot\fi}

\def\tocline#1#2#3#4#5{{\leftskip=#1\iindent \rightskip=2\iindent
   \ifischap\advance\leftskip by\iindent\fi
   \ifnum#1>1 \advance\leftskip by\iindent\fi
   \toclinehook \noindent\llap{#2\toclink{#3}\enspace}%
         {#2#4\unskip}\nobreak\nobreak\hskip-2\iindent\null\par}}

% slideshow with \kuk     
\let\kuk=\relax 
\def\kukdata{}
\long\def\kukstart#1\kuk{\addto\kukdata{#1}%
   \tmpnum=0 \def\endkukdata{}\expandafter\sumkuk \kukdata\sumkuk
   \kukdata\endkukdata \vfil\break \kukstart
}
\long\def\sumkuk#1{\ifx#1\sumkuk
   \loop \ifnum\tmpnum>0 \addto\endkukdata{\enditems}\advance\tmpnum by-1 \repeat
   \else 
     \ifx#1\begitems \global\advance\tmpnum by1 \fi 
     \ifx#1\enditems \global\advance\tmpnum by-1 \fi
     \expandafter\sumkuk \fi
}
\count1=1  
\def\advancepageno{\ifx\kukdata\empty \global\advance\pageno by1 \global\count1=1
                   \else \global\advance\count1 by1 \fi}
\def\pg{\def\kukdata{}\vfil\break}

\newif\iffirstslide

\def\sec#1\par{\ifnonum\else \global\advance\secnum by1 \fi
  \sechook {\globaldefs=1 \seccnum=0 \tnum=0 \fnum=0 \dnum=0}\relax
  \edef\thesecnum{\othe\chapnum.\the\secnum}\let\thetocnum=\thesecnum
  \iffirstslide
    \def\dotocnumafter{\wtotoc1\rm{#1}}%
  \else
    \def\dotocnumafter{}%
  \fi
  \firstslidefalse 
  \printsec{#1\unskip}\resetnonumnotoc
}

\def\pg{\def\kukdata{}\firstslidetrue\vfil\break}



\kukstart                           % if \kukstart in comment, it prints document normal

\tit Slideshow in \TeX

\pg

\hbox{\hbox to0cm{\vtop{\hsize=6cm \subfont \noindent TOC:

\maketoc}} \hskip6cm \hbox to0cm{\vtop{\hsize=10cm {\nonum\sec First slide

\kuk
* First item
\kuk
* Second item
\kuk
* Third item
}}}}

\pg\kuk

\nonum\sec Second slide

\kuk
* First item
\kuk
* Second item
\kuk
* Third item

\pg\kuk

\nonum\sec Third slide

\kuk
* First item 
\kuk
* Second item 
\kuk
* Third item

\enditems
\end
\kuk
```

But the result is:

[image]

There is no header (`\firstmark` does not work) and the macro `\kuk` also does not work. There are also ugly black strikes after `\hbox`. How can I fix it?

Please only a plain-tex solution.

Thank you very much!

Comment: you can get rid of the "black strikes" either by setting `\overfullrule=0pt` or seeing how overfull those `\hbox`es are by looking in the log, and setting `\hfuzz=` a value just slightly larger than the reported overage.  (the other problems are more complicated, and i don't have easy solutions.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton The overfull boxes are caused by `\hbox to 0cm{\vtop{\hsize=6cm ...}}`. This can be fixed by `\hbox to 0cm{...\hss}` or putting the following `\hskip 6cm` into the first `\hbox` specification: `\hbox to 6cm{\vtop{\hsize=6cm ...}}`. The second overfull box is fixed in a similar way.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek -- thanks.  i just took the easy, "brute force" approach.  your approach is much better, as it attacks the problem, not just the symptom.

Comment: You can be inspired by the ctuslides code, which uses opmac and implements more features to \kuk macro (dealing with verbatim text, renamed to \pg here). See http://petr.olsak.net/ftp/olsak/ctustyle/slides.pdf

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Overfull `\hbox` messages

The overfull boxes are caused by

```
\hbox to 0cm{\vtop{\hsize=6cm ...}}
```

Material with width 6 cm is larger than 0 cm.
This can be fixed by adding `\hss` at the end of the `\hbox`:

```
\hbox to 0cm{...\hss}
```

In this particular case, the 6 cm reappear after the box in `\hskip6cm`.

Thus the `\hskip` can be removed and added to the first `\hbox`
specification:

```
\hbox to 6cm{\vtop{\hsize=6cm ...}}
```

The second overfull box by the next `\hbox to 0cm{...}` can be fixed
in the same ways.

## `\firstmark` not working for slide "First slide".

The `\sec` command calls `\insertmark`, which sets the `\mark`. But the section "First slide" is inside a vertical box `\vtop`. The mark moves from paragraphs or from inside `\hbox` to the enclosing vertical box.
But this `\vtop` is not the main vertical list, the `\mark` remains captured and is therefore lost.

As workaround, the mark can be set manually:

```
\pg
\mark{First slide}
\hbox{\hbox ...\vtop{...\sec First slide ...
```

## `\kuk` not working

`\tracingmacros=1` reveals:

```
\kukstart #1\kuk ->\addto \kukdata {#1} [...]
#1<-\par \tit Slideshow in \TeX \par \pg \par \hbox {\hbox to0cm{\vtop {\hsize =6cm \subfont \noindent TOC: \par \maketoc }\hss
 } \hskip 6cm \hbox to0cm{\vtop {\hsize =10cm {\nonum \sec First slide \par \kuk * First item \kuk * Second item \kuk * Third item }}\hss }} \par \pg
```

When TeX looks for delimited arguments, then it reads anything until the delimiter. But the argument before must comply with the rule, that curly argument braces must be properly nested. Until the a closing brace is not found, it does not look for the delimiter. Thus the `\kuk` on the first slide are hidden inside several brace pairs of `\hbox` and `\vtop`.
(Here the curly braces could be relaced by `\bgroup` and `\egroup`, but the trouble comes then later, when the chunks are executed without the missing `\egroup` tokens.

As workaround, LaTeX package `atbegshi` can also be used in plain TeX. Then the table of contents could be set by overlaying the output page and the normal slide contents is set normally without surrounding box commands.

**Example:**

```
\input opmac
%\chyph

\input atbegshi.sty
\AtBeginShipoutInit
\def\abshook{}
\AtBeginShipout{\abshook{}}

\margins/1 a5l (1,1,1,1.2)cm        % page format
\input ctimes  \typosize[17/22]      % font

\def\pg{\vfil\break}                % new page
\begitems                           % start items

% set font
\letfont\titfont=\tenbf at18pt 
\letfont\subfont=\tenbf at16pt 

% set header
\headline={\ifnum\folio=1\hfill\else{\hbox to\hsize{\hfil \subfont \firstmark \hfil}}\fi}

% set footer
\newtoks\leftfoot \leftfoot={\hfill Footer text}
\newtoks\rightfoot \rightfoot={\hfill \subfont\folio} 
\footline={\ifnum\folio=1\hfill\else\the\leftfoot\the\rightfoot\fi}

\def\tocline#1#2#3#4#5{{\leftskip=#1\iindent \rightskip=2\iindent
   \ifischap\advance\leftskip by\iindent\fi
   \ifnum#1>1 \advance\leftskip by\iindent\fi
   \toclinehook \noindent\llap{#2\toclink{#3}\enspace}%
         {#2#4\unskip}\nobreak\nobreak\hskip-2\iindent\null\par}}

% slideshow with \kuk     
\let\kuk=\relax 
\def\kukdata{}
\long\def\kukstart#1\kuk{\addto\kukdata{#1}%
   \tmpnum=0 \def\endkukdata{}\expandafter\sumkuk \kukdata\sumkuk
   \kukdata\endkukdata \vfil\break \kukstart
}
\long\def\sumkuk#1{\ifx#1\sumkuk
   \loop \ifnum\tmpnum>0 \addto\endkukdata{\enditems}\advance\tmpnum by-1 \repeat
   \else 
     \ifx#1\begitems \global\advance\tmpnum by1 \fi 
     \ifx#1\enditems \global\advance\tmpnum by-1 \fi
     \expandafter\sumkuk \fi
}
\count1=1  
\def\advancepageno{\ifx\kukdata\empty \global\advance\pageno by1 \global\count1=1
                   \else \global\advance\count1 by1 \fi}
\def\pg{\def\kukdata{}\vfil\break}

\newif\iffirstslide

\def\sec#1\par{\ifnonum\else \global\advance\secnum by1 \fi
  \sechook {\globaldefs=1 \seccnum=0 \tnum=0 \fnum=0 \dnum=0}\relax
  \edef\thesecnum{\othe\chapnum.\the\secnum}\let\thetocnum=\thesecnum
  \iffirstslide
    \def\dotocnumafter{\wtotoc1\rm{#1}}%
  \else
    \def\dotocnumafter{}%
  \fi
  \firstslidefalse 
  \printsec{#1\unskip}\resetnonumnotoc
}

\def\pg{\def\kukdata{}\firstslidetrue\vfil\break}


\kukstart                           % if \kukstart in comment, it prints document normal

\tit Slideshow in \TeX

\pg
\kuk

\def\abshook{%
  \immediate\write16{* ABS, page: \the\count0}%
  \setbox\AtBeginShipoutBox=\hbox{%
    \setbox0=\hbox to 0pt{%
      \dimen0=\vsize
      \advance\dimen0 by 1.2cm
      \raise\dimen0\vtop to 0pt{%
        \kern0pt
        \bigskip
        \hsize=6cm
        \leftskip=\iindent
        \subfont
        \noindent TOC:

        \maketoc
        \par
        \vss
      }%
      \hss
    }%
    \ht0=0pt
    \dp0=0pt
    \wd0=0pt
    \copy0
    \copy\AtBeginShipoutBox
  }%
}

\leftskip=6cm

\nonum\sec First slide

\kuk
* First item
\kuk
* Second item
\kuk
* Third item

\pg\kuk

\leftskip=0pt
\def\abshook{}

\nonum\sec Second slide

\kuk
* First item
\kuk
* Second item
\kuk
* Third item

\pg\kuk

\nonum\sec Third slide

\kuk
* First item 
\kuk
* Second item 
\kuk
* Third item

\enditems
\end
\kuk
```

## Variant with `\prepghook`

```
\input opmac
%\chyph

\def\prepghook{%
  \vbox to0pt{%
    \kern-\voffset
    \kern-1in
    \hbox to0pt{%
      \kern-\hoffset
      \kern-1in
      \background
      \hss
    }%
    \vss
  }%
  \nointerlineskip
  \vbox to 0pt{%
    \kern 0pt
    \hbox to 0pt{%
      \kern-\iindent
      \tochook
      \hss
    }%
    \vss
  }%
  \nointerlineskip
}
\pdfximage width\pdfpagewidth height\pdfpageheight {tiger.pdf}
\mathchardef\picbackground=\pdflastximage
\def\background{\pdfrefximage\picbackground}
\let\pgfhook\prepghook
\def\tochook{}

\margins/1 a5l (1,1,1,1.2)cm        % page format
\input ctimes  \typosize[17/22]      % font

\def\pg{\vfil\break}                % new page
\begitems                           % start items

% set font
\letfont\titfont=\tenbf at18pt
\letfont\subfont=\tenbf at16pt

% set header
\headline={\ifnum\folio=1\hfill\else{\hbox to\hsize{\hfil \subfont \firstmark \hfil}}\fi}

% set footer
\newtoks\leftfoot \leftfoot={\hfill Footer text}
\newtoks\rightfoot \rightfoot={\hfill \subfont\folio}
\footline={\ifnum\folio=1\hfill\else\the\leftfoot\the\rightfoot\fi}

\def\tocline#1#2#3#4#5{{\leftskip=#1\iindent \rightskip=2\iindent
   \ifischap\advance\leftskip by\iindent\fi
   \ifnum#1>1 \advance\leftskip by\iindent\fi
   \toclinehook \noindent\llap{#2\toclink{#3}\enspace}%
         {#2#4\unskip}\nobreak\nobreak\hskip-2\iindent\null\par}}

% slideshow with \kuk
\let\kuk=\relax
\def\kukdata{}
\long\def\kukstart#1\kuk{\addto\kukdata{#1}%
   \tmpnum=0 \def\endkukdata{}\expandafter\sumkuk \kukdata\sumkuk
   \kukdata\endkukdata \vfil\break \kukstart
}
\long\def\sumkuk#1{\ifx#1\sumkuk
   \loop \ifnum\tmpnum>0 \addto\endkukdata{\enditems}\advance\tmpnum by-1 \repeat
   \else
     \ifx#1\begitems \global\advance\tmpnum by1 \fi
     \ifx#1\enditems \global\advance\tmpnum by-1 \fi
     \expandafter\sumkuk \fi
}
\count1=1
\def\advancepageno{\ifx\kukdata\empty \global\advance\pageno by1 \global\count1=1
                   \else \global\advance\count1 by1 \fi}
\def\pg{\def\kukdata{}\vfil\break}

\newif\iffirstslide

\def\sec#1\par{\ifnonum\else \global\advance\secnum by1 \fi
  \sechook {\globaldefs=1 \seccnum=0 \tnum=0 \fnum=0 \dnum=0}\relax
  \edef\thesecnum{\othe\chapnum.\the\secnum}\let\thetocnum=\thesecnum
  \iffirstslide
    \def\dotocnumafter{\wtotoc1\rm{#1}}%
  \else
    \def\dotocnumafter{}%
  \fi
  \firstslidefalse
  \printsec{#1\unskip}\resetnonumnotoc
}

\def\pg{\def\kukdata{}\firstslidetrue\vfil\break}


\kukstart                           % if \kukstart in comment, it prints document normal

\tit Slideshow in \TeX

\pg
\kuk

\def\tochook{%
  \immediate\write16{* ABS, page: \the\count0}%
  \setbox0=\vtop to 0pt{%
    \kern0pt
    \bigskip
    \hsize=6cm
    \leftskip=\iindent
    \subfont
    \noindent TOC:

    \maketoc
    \par
    \vss
  }%
  \ht0=0pt
  \dp0=0pt
  \wd0=0pt
  \copy0
}

\leftskip=6cm

\nonum\sec First slide

\kuk
* First item
\kuk
* Second item
\kuk
* Third item

\pg\kuk

\leftskip=0pt
\def\tochook{}

\nonum\sec Second slide

\kuk
* First item
\kuk
* Second item
\kuk
* Third item

\pg\kuk

\nonum\sec Third slide

\kuk
* First item
\kuk
* Second item
\kuk
* Third item

\enditems
\end
\kuk
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, your answer help me. I have tried use `atbegshi` package but I find only some LaTeX examples. Could you explain me, how can I use it in TeX in my case...? Or do you know any web with the examples, please?

Comment: I used your example, but if I set a background `\def\prepghook{\vbox to0pt{\kern-\voffset\kern-1in \hbox to0pt{\kern-\hoffset\kern-1in\background\hss}\vss} \nointerlineskip } \pdfximage width\pdfpagewidth height\pdfpageheight {background_1.pdf} \mathchardef\picbackground=\pdflastximage \def\background{\pdfrefximage\picbackground}`, the text is under this background. How can I set the box above the background..? Thank you

Comment: @Mori The code in the comment define some macros, but they are unused and do not add anything.

Comment: The macro sets the file "background_1.pdf" as the background...  There is a result: http://postimg.org/image/x6ucbks4r/.

Comment: @Mori The code in the comment only defines `\prepghook`, `\picbackground` and `\background`. Neither of them are used in my version of `opmac` (April 2015) nor in the code of the question. Thus I do not know, how the background image is added. If this works for you, then you could add the table of contents on top of the background image in the hook `\prepghook`. That should not be too difficult for a plain TeX user.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek IMHO, the source of the usage of `\prepghook` is at the page http://petr.olsak.net/opmac-tricks-e.html#podklad where is written: The `\background` is placed exactly to the left up corner of the paper using `\prepghook` macro (available from OPmac May 2015).

Comment: @wipet Thanks, my version was too old. Answer is now updated with a variant which uses `\prepghook` instead of package `atbegshi`.